# node js file on centos running but not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos

I have a .js file that is correctly working on another cent os vps, but on my vps when i run it using :

```
screen
node nodefile.js
```

I get nothing as output and when i try to use it using it's listening port (9615) i don't get anything as result, I've already installed node js following this tutorial :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit

any suggestions please ??

Comment: post us your nodefile.js content, granted it is of a reasonable size.

Comment: My first suggestion: please [read this important essay](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). I will help you a lot getting meaningful answers and saving time.

Comment: it's huge, using several other .js files, but i'm sure about it, it's working on my other vps correcly, but i didn't installed node and ran .js file on it myself.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.
+ that I'm in hurry... :)